# C# .NET Core: Efficiently Download and Unzip Many Zip Archives

Tags: c#, optimization, .net-core, download, archive

The task is to download many (<5k) small zip archives (e.g., >10MB each) and extract their data to separate folders. A naive approach would be download and extract the archives one-by-one, though it will work, but would take a considerable amount of time to complete.

I can put the code in a parallel foreach and concurrently download and extract multiple archives. But I get the point that since my task is a combination of I/O and CPU bound operations, I will have points in time where all the threads are waiting for downloads to complete and (almost) at the same time (since archives are about the same size) all will start unzipping, hence the threads are "wasted" when waiting for downloads to complete. So, I guess I should be using a "combination" of async download and multiple threads. Ideally I would like to have a code where while threads are waiting for multiple downloads to complete, the same threads start unzipping any downloaded archive, and once each has completed the unzipping process, it triggers a new download.

The code downloading and unzipping sequentially is as follows, any suggestion how that can be optimised?

```cs
foreach (var archive in archives)
{
    string zipFileName = tmpPath + archive.Id;
    var downloadTask = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadFileTaskAsync(
        address: archive.Uri,
        fileName: zipFileName);

    string extractPath = tmpPath + archive.Id + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
    Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPath);

    await downloadTask;
    using (ZipArchive zipFile = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipFileName))
        foreach (var entry in zipFile.Entries)
            entry.ExtractToFile(extractedFileName);
}
```

### Update 1: Using TPL

Following uses TPL; however, not sure why `extractor` is not invoked until `downloader` has finished downloading all the linked content, and `processor` is not invoked until `extractor` has finished extracting all the archives. I expect multiple parallel downloads happening in `downloader` and as soon as any download is completed, it should be passed to `extractor`, and while the `extractor` is extracting the archive all the other downloads should resume, and as soon as the `extractor` has finished extracting the archive, it should invoke `processor` on the extracted content. In other words, I expect these "blocks" to be executed in parallel with multiple threads running in each (intra- and cross-parallelization), but the following code invokes blocks in serial and executes each block with multiple threads.

```cs
var exeOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
};

var linkOptions = new DataflowLinkOptions
{
    PropagateCompletion = true
};

var downloader = new TransformBlock<string, string>(new Func<string, string>(Download), exeOptions);
var extractor = new TransformBlock<string, string>(new Func<string, string>(Extract), exeOptions);
var processor = new ActionBlock<string>(input => { Process(input); }, exeOptions);

downloader.LinkTo(extractor, linkOptions);
extractor.LinkTo(processor, linkOptions);

foreach (var url in urls)
    downloader.Post(tool);

downloader.Complete();

await processor.Completion;
```

Comment: Look for TPL DataFlow - it is exactly for that kind of work

Comment: Sounds interesting, any example? or light-weight alternative solution?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `WebClient` rather than `HttpClient`?

Comment: `any suggestion how that can be optimised?` Don't `await` **individual** entries.

Comment: @SirRufo following those examples my second block does not start until the first block has completed processing __all__ its input, even setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` does not help.

Comment: @SirRufo see my updated code.

Comment: See my sample [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P1ijpi) - It is important to set the MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a realistic value. Download is IO-bound and Unzip is CPU-bound. You should limit the Download to a value depending on the possible bandwidth and connections to the server (sometimes you have to guess and using less is sometimes more) and the Unzip to the system Processor count.